# In Android how to apply and preview themes during app dev in a faster manner?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

While developing an android application we may have to choose among different themes that goes with our activity.The process of choosing it from: App theme->Holo->Theme.Holo for instance, is a bit tedious and time consuming process.Is there any plugin or a faster way, using which I can preview the themes for my activities?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I really dont have a sure answer but i think the best bet is to debug with a real android device rather than an emulator . It loads faster and all that

PS : beginner's advice